# Errors from PHP-FPM not timestamped in nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm running php-fpm 7.2 and nginx 1.14 from package on Ubuntu 18.04.

Messages originating from nginx are written to the error log prefixed with a date/time, but the log entries emitted by PHP-FPM (recorded in nginx's error_log) have no date/time prefix.

I don't see anything obvious in either the php-fpm nor nginx config to adddress this.